# How to implement parameterized data binding in Polymer?

Tags: polymer

There is a custom component, e.g. address. Look at the code below.

```
            <simple-address name="address" label="Address" id="address"
                            data$="[[data.address]]">
            </simple-address>
```

[[data.address]] is passed from the parent control. How to pass address as parameter? For example, if I change the name using dom operation, I need to pass the similar data to simple-address control. If the name of control become 'customer-address', the data should be data$="[[data.cusomer-address]]".

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a computed binding

```
<simple-address name="address" label="Address" id="address"
    data={{_computeData(data)}}">
</simple-address>

...........

_computeData: function(data) {
    ....
    return val;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It's really help.